# C++ listview delete items

Tags: listview, winapi

I have a dialog window with 3 controls: listview, group box (used to contain the listview), delete button.

**Expected:** When a list item is selected, and the delete button is clicked, a message box states which ID is to be deleted, and that item is removed from the list.

**Actual:** the message box displays the correct selected ID, but it is always the last list item that gets deleted. Not the selected item.

```cpp
///// constructor

    hWndListView = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, WC_LISTVIEW, NULL,
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE |
        WS_BORDER | WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL | LVS_REPORT,
        rcClient.left, rcClient.top,
        (rcClient.right - rcClient.left), (rcClient.bottom - rcClient.top),
        hDlgTest, (HMENU)NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), this
    );
```

```cpp
///// Dialog Proc

INT_PTR CALLBACK listviewProc(HWND hDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_NOTIFY:
        HandleWM_NOTIFY(hDlg, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
        break;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case IDC_DELSELITEM:
        {
            listId = SendMessage(hListView, LVM_GETNEXTITEM, -1, LVNI_SELECTED);
            if (listId != -1)
            {
                SendMessage(hListView, LVM_DELETEITEM, listId, 0);

                std::string sText = "The value is: " + std::to_string(listId);
                MessageBox(hDlg, sText.c_str(), "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
            }
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
}
```

```cpp
///// Subitems

BOOL insertListViewItems(HWND hListView, int cItems)
{
    LVITEM lvI;

    lvI.pszText = LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACK;
    lvI.mask = LVIF_TEXT | LVIF_IMAGE | LVIF_STATE;
    lvI.stateMask = 0;
    lvI.iSubItem = 0;
    lvI.state = 0;

    // Initialize LVITEM members that are different for each item.
    for (int index = 0; index < cItems; index++)
    {
        lvI.iItem = index;
        lvI.iImage = index;

        // Insert items into the list.
        if (ListView_InsertItem(hListView, &lvI) == -1)
            return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Don't mind my awesome list content!

[image: SCRREEN SHOT]

**edit**

```
void HandleWM_NOTIFY(HWND hDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    NMLVDISPINFO* plvdi;

    switch (((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code)
    {
    case LVN_GETDISPINFO:

        plvdi = (NMLVDISPINFO*)lParam;

        switch (plvdi->item.iSubItem)
        {
        case 0:
            plvdi->item.pszText = rgPetInfo[plvdi->item.iItem].szKind;
            break;

        case 1:
            plvdi->item.pszText = rgPetInfo[plvdi->item.iItem].szBreed;
            break;

        case 2:
            plvdi->item.pszText = rgPetInfo[plvdi->item.iItem].szPrice;
            break;

        case 3:
            plvdi->item.pszText = rgPetInfo[plvdi->item.iItem].szBlah;
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        break;
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198759/discussion-on-question-by-bradmage-c-listview-delete-items).

Comment: Yes, if there is an answer, please post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

With some help from the comments, the answer is: ListView_DeleteItem removes one list item, but then WM_NOTIFY refreshes the original data from the array just with one less element. It appears to be deleting from the end of the list, but it's actually refreshing the list with fresh data after the delete.

The solution was to make the array a vector for easier control. And remove the index from the array and the listview at the same time.

```
ListView_DeleteItem(hListView, listId);
listVector.erase(listVector.begin() + listId);
```